# How do I defeat Bloodwing in the 'Wildlife Preservation' quest?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can anyone offer me any guidance on the Wildlife Preservation quest, namely the part where you weaken Bloodwing. I realize there is a small spot over to the right intended to help you dodge her divebombs, but between fighting her and the Skags it's just so chaotic.

I've spent easily two to three thousand dollars on respawns at the New-U, but I eventually thought it was best to just go back to Sanctuary, do some side quests, level up, and come back and try to do the Wildlife Preservation quest. My personal problem is that I've never gotten past her shock elemental state. Divebombs aren't a problem, as I've explained before.

So anyway, can you offer some help beyond my own?

Comment: Which character are you playing as?

Comment: Do you play on PC ? (not relevant to the answer but I can give a hand in BL2 if you play on PC)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difficulties you're facing? I've never considered this a very hard fight.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limitted amount of info all i can say is you have to do 2 things:

1) go back and level up (more health = more chance to survive)
2) try to get better gear

I could probably give much better advice if i knew which mode you're on, your level, your class and your equipment. 
Though word of advice, in that map before bloodwing, theres a set of 4 cardboard boxes next to a red chest. if you're on the mission "Doctor's orders", these boxes have a really high chance of spawning loot midgets. so you can farm them for orange gear. (also a chance to spawn jenkins if going for the "challenge accepted"  achievement)

Answer (score 0):

there are any number of reasons the Bloodwing fight can be difficult, but here's the most common fixes;

1. you may just be under-leveled. remember, BL is a very interesting series in that, yeah after a little while even if you're under-leveled you might be able to get somewhere, but there usually is a spot where you can't continue regardless. try and make sure you're leveled enough to handle it.
2. Bloodwing has multiple phases throughout the fight where her Elemental status changes, and for those on the Internet just reading for a walkthrough, that's evident by the colored texturing (eg. she starts as Corrosion, I believe, then with Incendiary, then Shock, and finally Slag). For each (minor exception of Slag), you need to swap out weapons according to her Elemental status, otherwise she becomes immune to your shots should they match.

if none of these are the problem (eg. you're dealing damage, but not enough), then you might just not have a large enough shield capacity to deal with it. i personally fought as Zer0 using the Law and Order combination for a good majority of my playthrough, included with the "melee attacks give back health" skills set within my tree, so my character kinda took the easy way out of things--if you used Axton or Salvador, for example, i can't give specific help there--but having a large shield and/or large HP definitely helps, as you're not eaten alive by the Skags before you know they're even there.

Answer (score -3):

my best advice would be to go down the elevator,die,then respawn at the top. i would recommend axton. then throw your turret down the elevator. when bloodwing lands, snipe her at the top of the elevator without ever having to enter the arena.note: she still may be able to hit you.

Comment: Downvoted because advice to "be Axton" is not really helpful in a game where progress is tied to specific characters.

Answer (score -3):

I would use Axton's Sabre Turret ability. You'd also need a second player, so if you die, have them go in the arena so Bloodwing doesn't regain her health.